# Using RX, TX pins with IoT Core

Tags: pi-2, windows-iot, uart

I was trying to find some references about this topic but I didn't find any, so I decided to post this question first before buying something that won't work. Does IoT Core supports this? If so can you give me a link "how" to communicate with devices in such way?

Comment: I find it near to impossible to conceive that the UART should not be usable on IoT.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[Serial Port Sample](https://ms-iot.github.io/content/en-US/win10/samples/SerialSample.htm) explicetly mentions the Raspberry Pi and the use of its on-board UART as "verified to work":

> On-board UART (Rasperry Pi2)
>
> The Rasperry Pi 2 or 3 has one on-board UART. See the Raspberry Pi 2 Pin Mappings page for more details on the GPIO pins.
>
> ```
> UART0 uses GPIO pins 6 (GND), 8 (TX) and 10 (RX).
> ```